# Laravel belongsTo method returns null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a 'Waitlist' model which has the following relationship:

```
public function pet()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Pet::class, 'pet_id');
}
```

If I call `$waitlist->pet` I get null, but the `$waitlist` object does have a valid `pet_id` property.

Update:

These are my migration files:

```
 Schema::create('waitlists', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('team_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('pet_id')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('pet_id')
                ->references('id')->on('pets');

            $table->foreign('team_id')
                ->references('id')->on('teams')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    
Schema::create('pets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('pet_type_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('pet_breed_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->enum('sex', ['male', 'female'])->nullable();
            $table->string('microchip')->nullable();
            $table->date('dob')->nullable();
            $table->date('adoption_date')->nullable();
            $table->string('origin')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('spayed')->nullable();
            $table->string('main_colour')->nullable();
            $table->string('distinguishing_features')->nullable();
            $table->date('first_vaccinations')->nullable();
            $table->date('second_vaccinations')->nullable();
            $table->date('latest_vaccinations')->nullable();
            $table->date('kennel_cough')->nullable();
            $table->date('rabies')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('pet_type_id')
                ->references('id')->on('pet_types')
                ->onDelete('set null');

            $table->foreign('pet_breed_id')
                ->references('id')->on('pet_breeds')
                ->onDelete('set null');
        });


What am I missing?
```

Comment: Does `Pet::findOrFail($waitlist->pet_id)`  work?

Comment: It doesn't work "No query results for model [App\\Pet] 10". I can see the row in the database table though.

Comment: Is your foreign key set up correctly in the database? Do you get a correct result of executing a SQL query joining the two tables? Check the SQL the query builder creates using `->toSql()` in place of `->get()`. Add the results of those checks and the migration code for your tables to your question if you don't find the problem.

Comment: What do you see in the database row?

Comment: what is the primary key in your pets table ?i f it's `pet_id` and not `id`, you need to define it in your pet model

Comment: you need to provide some information about database. primary key of your pet table. if it is 'id' then its fine but if its not then there is a problem. also you need to paste your migrations code in the question. that is helpful.

Comment: The migration doesn't seem to have any problem. Are you absolutely sure the database contains a row with id=10 inside the `pets` table?

Comment: @N69S may I know why you reject [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28321341) suggested edit?

Comment: @reans - Have you resolved this problem? If not please show the data you have in your tables, and post the output of the SQL from the query builder using `->toSql()`

Comment: @Tony yes got it sorted now - thank you for your help. It seems there was a scope applied I was not aware of that was causing mutually exclusive logic to filter out any potential matches.